# Why won't my blackjack program subtract 10 from the Aces when the score is over 21?

Tags: list, for-loop

I'm writing a program to play a basic version of blackjack. I can get the program to deal new cards to the player and sum the total of the cards values to get the score. I of course want the cards with the value "11" to be reduced to value 1 when the players score is over 21, but it won't change the values and update the player's hand and score when it tuns through the for loop.

```
   else:
          player_hand.append(deal_card())
          player_score = sum(player_hand)
        if player_score > 21:
          for card in player_hand:
            if card == 11:
               card = 1
               player_score = sum(player_hand)
        print(player_hand)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, because when you do

```
for card in player_hand:
```

it creates a new copy of each element in the list

and when you do

```
card = 1
```

it doesn't change the element inside of the array, it changes the copy, which gets deleted after the loop

instead, try using the index of the array

```
for i, card in enumerate(player_hand):
    if card == 11:
        player_hand[i] = 1
player_score = sum(player_hand)
```

the enumerate() method, makes a list of tuples, where

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
enumerate(my_list) = [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```